# Inserting predefined paragraph number in page header - follow up

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, paragraphs

I am following up further on the questions in:
[Inserting predefined paragraph numbers in page header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257599/inserting-predefined-paragraph-numbers-in-page-header/260914#260914)
I was not allowed to comment on this issue so had to create a new question.

@Andrew. @Sujato has gone offline for a few months and asked me to take over this issue as I have the main document.

I still have some issues left. One of them is that your hack on point 6 created a new page break in between the chapter-heading and the first section, which was not there before. Any ideas on how to overcome this issue?

EDIT: New MWE - hope this is OK now.

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlipsumdefault{1}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[explicit,raggedright]{titlesec}
\usepackage[tocflat]{tocstyle}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{hanging}

%TABLE OF CONTENTS%
\settocstylefeature[]{leaders}{\hfill}
\settocstylefeature[]{entryhook}{}
\settocstylefeature[]{raggedhook}{\raggedright}
\settocstylefeature[]{entryvskip}{0.2em}
\settocstylefeature[0]{entryvskip}{1em}
\settocstylefeature[0]{entryhook}{\bfseries}
\settocstylefeature[0]{pagenumberbox}{\csname @gobble\endcsname}
\renewcommand*{\cfttoctitlefont}{\Large}
%TABLE OF CONTENTS%

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filcenter}
{}
{1ex}
{\Huge {#1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
\markboth{#1}{#1}}


\titleformat{\section}
  {\centering\Large\mdseries}{\thesection}{1em}{\caps{#1}}

  \titleformat{\subsection}
  {\mdseries\large\raggedright}{}{}{#1}

  \titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\mdseries\raggedright}{}{}{#1}


%HEADER and FOOTER% 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[CO]{\headcaps{\MakeUppercase{\rightmark}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
   \markright{#1}%
   \def\firstpara{0}\def\midpara{0}\def\lastpara{0}
}
\fancyhead[CE]{\headcaps{\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\ifnum\firstpara>0\relax\footnotesize MN \thesection.\theparagraph\fi}

\newcommand\headcaps[1]{{ #1}}
\let\realSection\section
\renewcommand\section[2][\relax]{\clearpage%
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \ifx#1\relax\relax\realSection{#2}%
  \else\realSection[#1]{#2}%
  \fi
}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\def\firstpara{0}%
\def\midpara{0}%
\def\lastpara{0}%
\def\setparagraph#1-#2-#3|{\def\midpara{#1}%
   % if \firstpara=0 => new page => set \firstpara
   \ifnum\firstpara=0\relax\def\firstpara{#1}\fi%
   % if #2=0 => only #1 is meaningful to set \lastpara to this
   % otherwise use #2
   \ifnum#2=0\relax\def\lastpara{#1}%
   \else\def\lastpara{#2}%
   \fi%
}
\def\paragraph#1{\textbf{#1}\space%
  \setparagraph#1-0-|%
}
\def\theparagraph{
  % if \firstpara=\lastpara print only \firstpara otherwise print a range
  \ifnum\firstpara=\lastpara\relax\firstpara\else\firstpara-\lastpara\fi
  % reset firstpara and lastpara
  \xdef\firstpara{\midpara}%
  %\let\lastpara\relax%
}
% need to reset \firstpara on pages without headers
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ 
  \fancyhf{} 
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
  \fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\ifnum\firstpara>0\relax\footnotesize MN \thesection.\theparagraph\fi}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
%HEADER & FOOTER%

\setcounter{section}{0} %This can be a higher number f.i. in volume 2

%WIDOWS & ORPHANS% 
\widowpenalty=1000
\clubpenalty=1000
%WIDOWS & ORPHANS%


\date{}

\title{Document Title}
\author{Author Name}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{empty}

\maketitle

\newpage

\newpage

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter*{Preface}

\lipsum

\mainmatter

\chapter*{The First chapter}

\section{First section}

\paragraph{1}\lipsum

\paragraph{2}\lipsum

\paragraph{3-5}\lipsum

\paragraph{6}\lipsum

\paragraph{7-17}\lipsum

\paragraph{18}\lipsum

Paragraph without number

\paragraph{19-20}\lipsum

\paragraph{21-28}\lipsum

\paragraph{29}\lipsum

\paragraph{30}\lipsum

\section{Second Section}

\paragraph{1}\lipsum

\paragraph{2}\lipsum

\paragraph{3-5}\lipsum

\paragraph{6}\lipsum

\subsection*{Some subsection}

\paragraph{7-17}\lipsum

\paragraph{18}\lipsum

\paragraph{19-20}\lipsum

\paragraph{21-28}\lipsum

\paragraph{29}\lipsum

\paragraph{30}\lipsum

\chapter*{Second Chapter}

\section{Third Section}

\paragraph{1}\lipsum

\paragraph{2}\lipsum

\paragraph{3}\lipsum

\subsection*{Some subsection}

\paragraph{4}\lipsum

\paragraph{5}\lipsum

\subsubsection*{Some subsubsection}

\paragraph{6}\lipsum

\paragraph{7}\lipsum

\paragraph{8}\lipsum

\paragraph{9}\lipsum

\paragraph{10}\lipsum

\paragraph{11}\lipsum

\paragraph{12}\lipsum

\paragraph{13}\lipsum

\paragraph{14}\lipsum

\paragraph{15}\lipsum

One more line

\paragraph{16}\lipsum

\paragraph{17}\lipsum

\paragraph{18}\lipsum

\paragraph{19}\lipsum

\paragraph{20}\lipsum

\end{document}
```

There are two issues in this MWE as we had discussed below:

1. The chapter headings are on a separate page now instead of on the same page as the section heading following the chapter.
2. The paragraph numbers don't always correctly reflect the numbers on that page - in the screenshot on the bottom of page 4 the numbers are 7-20 and should be 7-18 [image: see screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you concretize your question with an example?

Comment: @Andrew suggested to replace the following code: `\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\newpage\thispagestyle{plain}}`  
with  `\let\realSection\section  
\renewcommand\section[2][\relax]{\clearpage%  
\thispagestyle{plain}%  
\ifx#1\relax\relax\realSection{#2}%  
\else\realSection[#1]{#2}%  
\fi  
}`  This fixed the issue as described in point 6 in the aforementioned post but it also created a new issue, namely a new page break in between the chapter heading and the first section.

Comment: OK, perhaps I misunderstood. I thought that you wanted every section to start on a new page. Is it true that you want every section EXCEPT for the first section to start on the first page? If so then replacing the `\clearpage` with `\ifnum\arabic{section}>1\clearpage\fi` will do what you want.

Comment: @Andrew - That would also not quite work because the sectionnumber after a chapter is not always 1. The main document has 152 sections numbered 1-152, divided into 15 chapters and there is no clear logic as to where the chapter headings go (it's an ancient text).

Comment: The section number is reset at the start of each chapter. In fact, it above it should be `\ifnum\arabic{section}>1\clearpage\fi` because the section number is reset to `0` rather than `1`. But I guess that you are saying that the chapters and section numbers are not related in a standard way. *Returning to my question*, is it true that you want a page break before every section EXCEPT for the first section in a chapter. If this is what you want then I can post a way of doing this without using the section numbers.

Comment: A second problem I came across with this is that the paragraph numbers do not always correspond to the ones on the page. See image below. I added a `\subsection` in between in your MWE to make this clear. ![Output example - note the par.16 is mentioned on the previous page header](https://sujatoeurope.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/screenshot-from-2015-08-12-102838.png)

Comment: @Andrew - Yes, sorry, indeed I want a page break before every section EXCEPT for the first section in a chapter.

Comment: I just noticed your "second problem". Your image suggests that you are also using `\subsection` commands. Is this right? Subsections have never been mentioned before now and they are likely to cause the same problems with the section numbers in the headings. Please edit your question to say *exactly* how subsections should behave.

Comment: @Andrew - Subsections are used but they do not start a new page - they just remain where they happen to be on the page. The problem also occurs when there is no subsection there at all, but a new page happens to start with a new paragraph (like in this case par 16) - this paragraph number is then also shown in the header of the previous page. Just to illustrate this: ![screenshot of problem without subsection](https://sujatoeurope.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/screenshot-from-2015-08-12-143821.png)

Comment: I think that this is the same problem as previously: `\paragraph` is executed before the page break *but* LaTeX then decides that the paragraph will not fit on the page so it, instead, inserts a page break and starts a new page with the paragraph at the top. Unfortunately, the paragraph markers are now wrong in the header. For sections this was fixable because we forced a page-break. I'm not sure how to test if a paragraph is moved on shipout...

Comment: Can you please post a *full* [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that has sections and subsections and exhibits *all* of the problems that you want solved. If you give me this then I can try to solve your problems. Also, please tell me whether you need to use the titlesec package or whether this can be removed.

Comment: Hi @Andrew - Do you have some time free? I have solved most of the problems now except for the one about the paragraphs being wrongly moved on shipout.

Comment: I should have time in the new year but this shipout problem I do not know how to solve...I'd probably manually insert pagebreaks?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a modified version of the code from [Inserting predefined paragraph numbers in page header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257599/inserting-predefined-paragraph-numbers-in-page-header/260914#260914). I think that this does what you want.

What I have one is made `\chapter` set a flag `\IsNewChaptertrue` which is then used by the `\section` command to determine whether or not it should start a new page using `\clearpage`.

I think that I tested this when I was answering the previous question and determined that the issue with the incorrect section numbers in the heading is caused by the `\sectionbreak` command from the  [titlesec package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec), but perhaps I am misunderstanding something.

Anyway, here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlipsumdefault{1}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage[hmargin=63mm,vmargin=68mm]{geometry}

% fancy headings as defined by the OP except we need to be more careful
% with plain headings
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{empty}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}% clear all header and footer fields
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\bfseries \thepage}%
  % need to reset \firstpara on pages without headers
  \xdef\firstpara{\midpara}%
}
\fancypagestyle{paragraphs}{
  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
  \fancyhead[CO]{\rightmark}
  \fancyhead[CE]{\leftmark}
  \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\ifnum\firstpara>0\relax\thesection.\theparagraph\fi}
}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
   \markright{#1}%
   % reset paragraph counters in each section
   \def\firstpara{0}\def\midpara{0}\def\lastpara{0}
}
\newif\ifIsNewChapter\IsNewChapterfalse
\let\realChapter\chapter
\renewcommand\chapter[2][\relax]{%
  \IsNewChaptertrue%
  \ifx#1\relax\relax\realChapter{#2}%
  \else\realChapter[#1]{#2}%
  \fi
}

\let\realSection\section
\renewcommand\section[2][\relax]{\ifIsNewChapter\relax\else\clearpage\fi
  \IsNewChapterfalse%
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \ifx#1\relax\relax\realSection{#2}%
  \else\realSection[#1]{#2}%
  \fi
}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

% now the macros for tracking the paragraph numbers
\def\firstpara{0}%    set to 1 by default
\def\midpara{0}%    set to 1 by default
\def\lastpara{0}% set to 1 by default
\def\setparagraph#1-#2-#3|{\def\midpara{#1}%
   % if \firstpara=0 => new page => set \firstpara
   \ifnum\firstpara=0\relax\def\firstpara{#1}\fi%
   % if #2=0 => only #1 is meaningful to set \lastpara to this
   % otherwise use #2
   \ifnum#2=0\relax\def\lastpara{#1}%
   \else\def\lastpara{#2}%
   \fi%
}
\def\paragraph#1{\textbf{#1}\space
  \setparagraph#1-0-|%
}
\def\theparagraph{%
  % if \firstpara=\lastpara print only \firstpara otherwise print a range
  \ifnum\firstpara=\lastpara\relax\firstpara\else\firstpara--\lastpara\fi
  % reset firstpara and lastpara
  \xdef\firstpara{\midpara}%
  %\let\lastpara\relax%
}

% back to the MWe
\begin{document}

\null
\pagestyle{empty}

\newpage

\newpage

\pagestyle{paragraphs}

\chapter{A Chapter}

\section{First Section}

\paragraph{1}\lipsum

\paragraph{2}\lipsum

\paragraph{3-5}\lipsum

\paragraph{6}\lipsum

\paragraph{7-17}\lipsum

\paragraph{18}\lipsum

\paragraph{19-20}\lipsum

\paragraph{21-28}\lipsum

\paragraph{29}\lipsum

\paragraph{30}\lipsum

\section{Second Section}

\paragraph{1}\lipsum

\paragraph{2}\lipsum

\paragraph{3-5}\lipsum

\paragraph{6}\lipsum

\paragraph{7-17}\lipsum

\paragraph{18}\lipsum

\paragraph{19-20}\lipsum

\paragraph{21-28}\lipsum

\paragraph{29}\lipsum

\paragraph{30}\lipsum

\section{Third Section}

\paragraph{1}\lipsum

\paragraph{2}\lipsum

\paragraph{3}\lipsum

\paragraph{4}\lipsum

\paragraph{5}\lipsum

\paragraph{6}\lipsum

\paragraph{7}\lipsum

\paragraph{8}\lipsum

\paragraph{9}\lipsum

\paragraph{10}\lipsum

\paragraph{11}\lipsum

\paragraph{12}\lipsum

\paragraph{13}\lipsum

\paragraph{14}\lipsum

\paragraph{15}\lipsum

\paragraph{16}\lipsum

\paragraph{17}\lipsum

\paragraph{18}\lipsum

\paragraph{19}\lipsum

\paragraph{20}\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew - I see where the confusion lies now. @Sujato has a lot more code in the main document than the MWE. The sectionnumber is not reset at the next chapter. Your solution works well in both the MWE and the real doc but in the real doc it creates a problem with the toc ... I have to look at this better and provide you with a good new MWE rather than to keep patching up things.

Comment: I have provided a full MWE now, without your latest change in it. There is a font in it that might need to be changed.

Comment: OK. Will take a look. I have a few days work that has to be finished first so I can't promise to get to you sooner.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew. Take your time - your help is very much appreciated! I'm very happy when this is done in 2 months time :-)

Comment: @Vimala A [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/)  is the smallest amount of code needed to exhibit your problem. It seems that your MWE wants me to use XeTeX or LuaTeX and I have not succeeded in getting it to compile, in part because I don't have the skolar fonts...I"m sure that none of this is really necessary.

Comment: I apologise, I'm new to all this. I've made a new one now that should compile and font taken out - I might still have left too much in because last time the mwe was too minimal. I have not added your latest code because that makes a mess with the toc/chapter headings.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew for your feedback on mwe. It really helps me to learn. Do you have some time to have a look at the new one I posted? Thanks!

Comment: @Vimala Sorry, work is OTT at the moment. Will try and get back to this...