# Add paragraph numbers to footer with titleps

Tags: paragraphs, titleps

I'm trying to add the first paragraph number on a page to the footer using titleps. However, it gives me just a chapter/sectionnumber followed by 3 zeros like 1.1.0.0.0.

Here is my code sofar:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlipsumdefault{1}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{fancy}{
\sethead[][\chaptertitle][] % even
                  {}{\sectiontitle}{} % odd
\setfoot[\thepage][][\theparagraph] % even
                  {\theparagraph}{}{\thepage}} % odd


% back to the MWe
\begin{document}

\null
\pagestyle{empty}

\newpage

\newpage

\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{A Chapter}

\section{First Section}

\paragraph{1}\lipsum

\paragraph{2}\lipsum

\paragraph{3-5}\lipsum

\paragraph{6}\lipsum

\paragraph{7-17}\lipsum

\paragraph{18}\lipsum

\paragraph{19-20}\lipsum

\paragraph{21-28}\lipsum

\paragraph{29}\lipsum

\paragraph{30}\lipsum

\section{Second Section}

\paragraph{1}\lipsum

\paragraph{2}\lipsum

\paragraph{3-5}\lipsum

\paragraph{6}\lipsum

\paragraph{7-17}\lipsum

\paragraph{18}\lipsum

\paragraph{19-20}\lipsum

\paragraph{21-28}\lipsum

\paragraph{29}\lipsum

\paragraph{30}\lipsum

\section{Third Section}

\paragraph{1}\lipsum

\paragraph{2}\lipsum

\paragraph{3}\lipsum

\paragraph{4}\lipsum

\paragraph{5}\lipsum

\paragraph{6}\lipsum

\paragraph{7}\lipsum

\paragraph{8}\lipsum

\paragraph{9}\lipsum

\paragraph{10}\lipsum

\paragraph{11}\lipsum

\paragraph{12}\lipsum

\paragraph{13}\lipsum

\paragraph{14}\lipsum

\paragraph{15}\lipsum

\paragraph{16}\lipsum

\paragraph{17}\lipsum

\paragraph{18}\lipsum

\paragraph{19}\lipsum

\paragraph{20}\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\arabic{paragraph}` in the place of `\theparagraph`.

Comment: Two problems: `\theparagraph` is defined to be `\thesubsection\arabic{paragraph}`, but you don't have any numbering enabled for paragraphs. To do that you would need to add `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}`. But `\theparagraph` will only contain the automatically numbered paragraph number, not the number you put in the argument to paragraph (which is simply its title.).

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting the result you get is because `\theparagraph` is defined as `\thesubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}`, which yields lots of dots and zeros because you haven't set the section counter depth.  But setting this won't solve your problem anyway, if you want your paragraphs to be numbered via the argument of `\paragraph` since that argument has no connection to the paragraph counter.

To do what you need to do, you need to do the following things:

1. Load `titlesec` with the `[pagestyles]` option instead of loading `titleps` directly (this is the correct way to load `titleps` if you are also using `titlesec`).
2. Enable titlemarks for the paragraph level using `\settitlemarks{...}`
3. Use `\paragraphtitle` in your footer definition.  This is because the argument of `\paragraph` is its title: even if you put numbers there, TeX has no way to know that it is a number unless you use a counter. Since you want arbitrary numbers, you need to use `\paragraphtitle` not `\theparagraph`.

### Update based on comment

If you want the numbers of the paragraphs to appear in the footer only, but not in the text itself, then you can redefine the `\paragraph` formatting using `titlesec`:

```
\makeatletter
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\@gobble}{}{}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{\parskip}{0pt}
\makeatother
```

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlipsumdefault{1}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{fancy}{
\sethead[][\chaptertitle][] % even
                  {}{\sectiontitle}{} % odd
\setfoot[\thepage][][\paragraphtitle] % even
                  {\paragraphtitle}{}{\thepage}} % odd

\settitlemarks{chapter,section,subsection,paragraph}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\@gobble}{}{}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{\parskip}{0pt}
\makeatother
% back to the MWe
\begin{document}

\null
\pagestyle{empty}

\newpage

\newpage

\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{A Chapter}

\section{First Section}

\paragraph{1}\lipsum

\paragraph{2}\lipsum

\paragraph{3-5}\lipsum

\paragraph{6}\lipsum

\paragraph{7-17}\lipsum

\paragraph{18}\lipsum

\paragraph{19-20}\lipsum

\paragraph{21-28}\lipsum

\paragraph{29}\lipsum

\paragraph{30}\lipsum

\section{Second Section}

\paragraph{1}\lipsum

\paragraph{2}\lipsum

\paragraph{3-5}\lipsum

\paragraph{6}\lipsum

\paragraph{7-17}\lipsum

\paragraph{18}\lipsum

\paragraph{19-20}\lipsum

\paragraph{21-28}\lipsum

\paragraph{29}\lipsum

\paragraph{30}\lipsum

\section{Third Section}

\paragraph{1}\lipsum

\paragraph{2}\lipsum

\paragraph{3}\lipsum

\paragraph{4}\lipsum

\paragraph{5}\lipsum

\paragraph{6}\lipsum

\paragraph{7}\lipsum

\paragraph{8}\lipsum

\paragraph{9}\lipsum

\paragraph{10}\lipsum

\paragraph{11}\lipsum

\paragraph{12}\lipsum

\paragraph{13}\lipsum

\paragraph{14}\lipsum

\paragraph{15}\lipsum

\paragraph{16}\lipsum

\paragraph{17}\lipsum

\paragraph{18}\lipsum

\paragraph{19}\lipsum

\paragraph{20}\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very nice. (I'm working with the OP on this, by the way.) Is it possible to do the same thing, but completely remove the paragraphtitle from the main text? In other words, the paragraphs are spaced and indented exactly as they would be without \paragraph. We just want the numbers in the footer without affecting the rest of the document.

Comment: So you essentially want the numbers to appear *only* in the footer, but be entered manually with the `\paragraph` command?

Comment: Yes, the numbers only in the footer. We don't don't care if it uses \paragraph or not, whatever way is easiest. We spent quite a bit of time on another approach (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257599/inserting-predefined-paragraph-numbers-in-page-header) but never got it working 100%. Using titleps is much cleaner. But at the end of the day, what we want is the predefined numbers in the footer, without affecting the paragraph styles..

Comment: @Sujato I've updated the answer.

Comment: That looks great, thanks so very much. Gobble! Now why didn't I think of that? Hopefully OP will accept this when she gets back on line.